# Task Not Running (Last Run Result 0x41325)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, task-scheduler

I have two tasks with the exact same settings.
Then only difference is the name of the Task of-cause.

One of them runs `Last Run Result: 0x0`.
The other however do not run `0x41325`.

Looking for ideas how to fix or debug this.

Comment: Try to running the task scheduler with admin privileges.

Comment: @stambata doesn't change anything. Anyways, was worth a try.

Comment: @stambata I changed the task for the one which didn't run properly which worked. I changed the user that the task would run as to the admin account. However, the order task is running correctly under `IIS_IUSRS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Task Scheduler Error and Success Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383604(v=vs.85).aspx), this error means that the task scheduler has asked the task to run. So it's not a security issue.

Check the task settings again, namely under which account the task is intended to run and "Run only when user is loggen on" setting. If the latter is set and the corresponding user is not logged on when Task Scheduler attempts to run the task the result code will be exactly this.